# Prevent shadow bleeding with position absolute element?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I'm developing a dropdown and I'm having an issue because I want to have an absolutely positioned container of items to appear when you hover over it, but the issue is that the shadow from this bleeds onto the actual dropdown itself. Here's a reproduction:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.dropdown:hover .items {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

As you can see, the top portion of the shadow from the `.items` container is visible when you mouse over the dropdown. Here's a picture of what I'm referring to:

[image]

The obvious solution is to just make the box shadow apply to *only* the dropdown, but then the issue is that since the `items` container is position absolute, it doesn't receive the box shadow.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jackson has the right idea with using a pseudo element.

Although my approach would be the following:

```css
.dropdown:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.dropdown:hover .items {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

A second approach could be to grow the height of .dropdown on hover, and set the items list to a position not relative to .dropdown's height:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 40px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.dropdown:hover .items {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  height: 140px;
}

.item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `:before` element on the `.dropdown` with a smaller height than he items. Like this:

```
.dropdown:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 98px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 24%) 0px 6px 8px;
    background: red;
    bottom: -100px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Also, remove the shadow from the `.items` element.